# windows 10 install freeze at beginning

Tags: windows-10, installation

I have hard time installing W10 on a new "homemade" computer that I bought used
Its configuration : MB :  gigabyte H510HM ver1.3 ; Proc : i3-10105F, GC :  GeForce FX970

Although, it ran OK with W10, my aim was to get it completely clean, as it has been used by someone else. I have an official W10 iso file with the associated license code which I know is OK because it was the license that I used on my former computer. So the first thing that I tried to do was to install my W10 iso to format the HD and then install my W10 (using a USB stick FAT32 or NTFS, GPT). When I tried that, the install process froze at the very beginning  (turning dots stopped turning). Here are the things that I tried but in every cases the install froze at the same point.

1. « secure boot » disabled, XMP disabled
2. Tried any of the USB ports and other USB sticks (with different format : MBR/BIOS). When I tried to enable CSM (just in case), the bios automatically  disable it.
3. I used a Gparted from a USBLIve UBUNTU to format the booting HD since I thought it might be a conflict with the already installed W10. I also unplugged the other HD. By the way, ubuntu ran just fine from the USBlive stick.
4. Flashed bios with the newer version and got the parameters to factory settings
5. tried other OS options on the MB bios (3 avalaible : other OS, Windows 10, W10 WHQL)
6. As I thought it might be a conflict with the GeForce Graphic card, I tried to unplugged it. But then, I have no signal coming out the VGA port of the MB. May be I have to activate it from the BIOS but I did not find how. I have no HDMI screen available to try the MB HDMI port. Edit : the processor is a F intel, so impossible to run without CG.
7. Tried to use the microsoft W10 creation tool to see what will happen and it actually worked till it asked me my license number … but then my older license number did not work without much surprise.
8. (edit) tried to run my USB on another computer and it worked fine up to asking the license code (but I did not go any further because I do not want to modify that OK-Computer) (blink to Radiohead :))

So now, I do not know what to do, and how to use my licensed version of W10 if possible. My iso-file is from 2015. So is it possible that the new computer with rather recent hardware is not compliant with this older W10 version ?

Had I not to share powerpoints with other people (impress is not as good) and use some other windows-specific softs, I definitely install ubuntu.

Thanks for reading this and maybe giving me some hints (sorry for misspelled items or other English errors as it is not my mother language)

Comment: Was this older computer was from an OEM?

Comment: no, home-made either... well rather a modified HP but "my" iso-windows was not the original one of that older computer.

Comment: no, home-made either... well rather a modified HP but "my" iso-windows was not the OEM one of that older computer. It was running win7 before and as the HD crashed I installed that non-OEM windows10 something like in  2015 or 2016 I guess.

Comment: I am (like @Ramhound) wondering about the license itself.. but I am unaware of prevention from installation or boot because of a license problem but still wonder if it isn't at the heart of this problem.  You English is GREAT!  Don't worry about that.

Comment: well I am not sure about a license issue since when I tried with a downloaded microsoft creation tool it ran fine until it asked me a license code. With "my" iso, it just got stuck at the running dots, just as if something wrong like a compatibility (or ageing) issue arises. (Thanx for the English)

Comment: @raoulpetite - Issues like that with a installation media, created with an ISO, typically suggest the ISO is the problem.

Comment: @ramhound. So you mean the iso file might have been corrupted or something like that ? It is a pity ....It worked a few years ago.

Comment: In my experience, if you boot to a media created by an ISO, and it does not work the problem likely was the ISO and is typically solved by using a fresh ISO. Which is the reason I ask for more information about the license, because if it was a Retail license, any Windows 10 ISO (of the appropriate edition) should work.

Comment: @Ramhound. Well I tried the iso from a USB stick  on a win10 laptop and it got to the license page without freezing. I did not get any further since I do not want to mess things up on that laptop. So, this "successful"  try get me back to an issue between "my" iso and the desktop that I am trying to fix.

Comment: Let me add that the laptop on which the iso ran fine is quite old (more than 7 years)